# Create new row depending on Column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table

```
ID|ProjectNr|Start|End|Name|
```

I want to generate an output like this:

```
|Name|End-Start for ID1|End-Start for ID2|
```

What I tried is

```
Select Name,
Case ProjectNr When 1 then datediff(Minute, Start, End) Else 0
From Table
```

I always get `From` underlined with the message `Incorrect Syntax near from`. Maybe I am blind but can anyone tell me what is wrong with the query please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the word `END` in the end of your `CASE` statement.

```
Select Name,
Case ProjectNr When 1 then datediff(Minute, Start, End) Else 0 END
From Table
```

Comment: Imagine I read throu the Case Entry on MSDN and didnt see it. I need a break. Thanks a lot!